# php : my header function didn't work.

Tags: php, netbeans, printing, header

my header function didn't work. 
I create 2 pages  test  and test2

ALL code in test :

```
<?php 
//header('Location ../index.php');
  header("Location ./test2.php"); ?>
```

ALL code in page test2

```
<?php   echo 'hello';    ?>
```

Why is my function does not work? No echo in front of it which is the most problem. This is all the code that is found in these two pages.

THANKS

Comment: do you know about network tab inside of browser console?

Comment: this is correct way to call header function :: header('Location: http://www.example.com/');

Comment: This code echo aaaaaa but header function didn't work.  

  `if((!(isset($_SESSION['logged-in'])))){
    header('Location: ../index.php');
    echo 'aaaaaaaaaaa';
}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have your syntax wrong, it should be (note the `:`):

```
<?php 
  header("Location: ./test2.php"); 
?>
```

providing the file is there it should work. Make sure the path is right though, currently you have it pointing to the same directory

Comment: oh yes, sorry. 
in the main code I have a problem,  does not want to move so I had to create these pages as a test to see whether header it works. Next step in my main code is check echo :)   thanks